# Add a default implementation of properties

Tags: c#, properties

I got the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return (string)Properties["property1"]; }
        set { Properties.Add("property1", value); }
    }
    public string Property2
    {
        get { return (string)Properties["property2"]; }
        set { Properties.Add("property2", value); }
    }

    //A lot more here

    public string Property30
    {
        get { return (string)Properties["property30"]; }
        set { Properties.Add("property30", value); }
    }

    public string Property31
    {
        get { return (string)Properties["property31"]; }
        set { Properties.Add("property31", value); }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm copying the getter and the setter a lot of times, which is kind of a hassle The class has about 20/30  properties. Is there a way to implement this automagically. I've done an implementation by making Foo dynamic and implementing the `TryGetMember`, but I don't like how the object isn't strongly typed anymore (especially the fact that there's no autocomplete in visual studio).

Cheers

Comment: You can also use Aspect Oriented Programming (for example PostSharp). It can do all that for you automagically as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can use [snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx). For properties, these are available by default. 
[image]

You can also [create your own](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx), or import snippets made by other developers or third parties using the Tools/Code Snippet Manager.

This is what your snippet would approximately look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>myprop</Title>
            <Shortcut>myprop</Shortcut>
            <Description></Description>
            <Author>Me</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>property</ID>
                    <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>MyProperty</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>field</ID>
                    <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
                    <Default>myVar</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;

    public $type$ $property$
    {
        get { return ($type$)Properties["$field$"];}
        set { Properties.Add("$field$",value);}
    }
    $end$]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Thanks, yea I ended up creating a snippet for it as well. It's just that I don't like having the similar implementation written over and over again in my source code. If I ever change the implementation, I have to refector all my properties.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post an alternative using [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/). Free version will work fine for this example. First install PostSharp from nuget, then create simple aspect:

```
[Serializable]
public class FooAspect : LocationInterceptionAspect {
    public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args) {
        var foo = ((Foo)args.Instance);
        if (foo.Properties == null || !foo.Properties.ContainsKey(args.LocationName))
            args.Value = null;
        else
            args.Value = foo.Properties[args.LocationName];
    }

    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args) {
        var foo = ((Foo) args.Instance);
        if (foo.Properties == null)
            foo.Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foo.Properties[args.LocationName] = args.Value;
    }
}
```

Here we basically intercept getters and setters of a property and rewriting them to use `Properties` dictionary instead of what they did before. Then apply aspect to `Foo` class (remember to exclude `Properties` property itself to avoid stack overflow):

```
[FooAspect(AttributeTargetMembers = "Property*")]
public class Foo
{        
    public string Property1 { get; set; }    
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public string Property30 { get; set; }
    public string Property31 { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties {get; set; }
}
```

Of course using PostSharp *just for this* is an overkill, but you might find it useful in many other cases too.

Comment: Ah cool. I'm already using PostSharp for some logging, so I'm going to try this out :) Seems like I still have a lot to learn about aspects.